# How can I open a dialog when the page is opened

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

In one of our page we have a search button that open a search dialog so that the users can search and import some data from a remote system.

Now got I new requirement that this same dialog must be showed every time the page is opened - but only when the page will be used to create a new registry, in the update mode it should be showed only if the user click the button.

I've already tried some things, I can call the dialog by MB using Primefaces engine as below:

```
 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dialogArmaBos.show()")
```

This command Works great for the button case, but I can get it working when the page opens. If I try to use in the PostConstruct nothing happens.

I tried also `<f:event type="preRenderView" ...` with `<f:metadata ...` but nothing changes too.

Is there some way to make it?

Comment: JSF or PrimeFaces won't help in this case, have a look into https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Just use `<p:dialog visible="true">`?

Comment: @Kukeltje based on what are you assuming that my suggestion is wrong ? there's nothing "Wrong" in a suggestion, either it fits your needs or it won't, if I was so sure that it's what the OP is looking for I would post it as an answer..

Comment: Yes you are correct about the fact that PF has a visible attribute, which I wasn't aware of.. in the end won't help is wrong :) @Kukeltje

Comment: Peeeaaaaccceeee... ;-) (my statement was a little to bold in hindsight, it was not meant this way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the fabulous [PrimeFaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf#page=181&zoom=auto,56.7,773.3) There is a visible attribute. Quote from the docs:

> visible   false   Boolean   When enabled, dialog is visible by default.

So simply use an EL in that attribute to have it show on pageload

```
<p:dialog visible="#{myBean.createMode}"... >
```

and have a boolean field in that bean that returns true if in creation mode.

For the rest you can show/hide it with the client-side api if needed